# Как в Java преобразовать double в обычную дробь с запятой, а затем в строку?

Tags: java

Вот это выражение

```
double dl = 5515.3661*1000;
```

на выходе дает в лог `5.1153661E7`
Как сделать чтоб на выходе оно давало `5515366,1`?

А затем преобразовать `5515366,1` в строку?

Comment: Млин, ну и прогеры пошли - не могут отличить представление числа от его форматирования. Куда этот мир катится?!

Answer (score 2):

класс Formatter посмотрите.. напр так

```
package my.test;

import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class FormatterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double dl = 5515.3661*1000;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter (sb, Locale.GERMANY);
        formatter.format("%10.1f",dl);                        
        System.out.println(formatter.toString());        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        double dl = 5515.3661*1000;
        float k = (float) Math.round(dl * 100) / 100;
        String str = Float.toString(k);
        out.println(str);
}
```